# id command with and without user specified

Tags: users

As in the title, I wonder why there exists any difference as below:

issue "**id**" without username:

```
ygl@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ id
uid=1001(ygl) gid=1002(ygl) groups=1002(ygl),112(nopasswdlogin)
```

with the logged-in username:

```
ygl@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ id ygl
uid=1001(ygl) gid=1002(ygl) groups=1002(ygl),112(nopasswdlogin),1000(lyg),1001(vboxsf)
```

Are there any places other than **/etc/group**  that store secondary groups for a user?

Comment: Can you post `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`?

Comment: @Eric Carvalho Yes, Of course.<br/>
`grep ygl /etc/passwd
ygl:x:1001:1002:YangLi,,,:/home/ygl:/bin/bash
grep ygl /etc/group
nopasswdlogin:x:112:ygl,usr2,usr1
lyg:x:1000:usr1,ygl
vboxsf:x:1001:ygl,lyg,usr1,usr3
ygl:x:1002:
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any places other than /etc/group that store secondary groups for a user?

No, the default Ubuntu setup only relies on `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` for group membership.

Your first `id` command there, shows the groups you are in in this logged in session (i.e. what group memberships `/etc/group` had at the moment you logged in).

Your second `id` command causes it to query `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, and displays information based on what those files currently contain.

Changes to group membership take effect when you log in.

Comment: I found what you mean in manual( type `info coreutilus 'id invocation'` in terminal ):


  `Primary and supplementary groups for a process are normally inherited
from its parent and are usually unchanged since login.  This means that
if you change the group database after logging in, 'id' will not
reflect your changes within your existing login session.  Running 'id'
with a user argument causes the user and group database to be consulted
afresh, and so will give a different result.`

thanks a lot!